# How do I show a hand symbol (cursor pointer) when the mouse hovers on date field in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to display cursor pointer when I mouse hover on TextField with type 'date'. I am providing the sandbox link below. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Sandbox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-5jcoq?file=/demo.tsx

code:-

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
 createStyles({
container: {
  display: 'flex',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
},
textField: {
  marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
  marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  width: 200,
},
}),
);

export default function DatePickers() {
const classes = useStyles();

return (
<form className={classes.container} noValidate>
  <TextField
    id="date"
    label="Birthday"
    type="date"
    defaultValue="2017-05-24"
    className={classes.textField}
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true,
    }}
  />
 </form>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use InputProps to pass props to the inner component. You can examine available classes [here](https://material-ui.com/api/input/).

```
InputProps={{ classes: { input: classes.input } }}
```

View [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialui-textfield-cursor-hkhde).

Comment: Thanks mate. But when I mouse hover on date icon in TextField, it is still not showing hand symbol. Is there any way to achieve that too?

Comment: Did you mean [this](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#icons) by saying "date icon". Your snippet does not contain this.

Comment: No mate. In the above reference an input adronment is used in the TextField. But here, that icon automatically displays when we use type="date" in the TextField.

Comment: Hmm, I think it is browser specific... In firefox there is no icon in right, but in chrome there is.

Comment: I think i achieved. Can you examine same codesandbox link?

Answer (score 1):

Add `hover` here:

```
`textField: {
  marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
  marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  width: 200,
 '&:hover': {
    cursor: "pointer"
  }
},`
```

and should do the trick